# Storing user input in list gives index out of bounds error

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to read user input into list of strings, but getting error when entering first value:

> Index must be within the bounds of the List.Parameter name: index

The problem is in the line `games.Insert(e, f);` It does not let me store the values. When exception happens `Insert` is called with:

```
   games.Insert(1, "test");
```

Full code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char g = 'w';
    string f;
    List<string> games = new List<string>();
    for (int e = 1; e <= 10; e++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("what are your favorite game" + e);
        f = (Console.ReadLine()).ToString();
        games.Insert(e, f);
    }

    while (g != 'q')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A for adding a game Q for quiting");
        g = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (g == 'a')
        {
            games.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing `games.Add(f);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`for (int e = 1; e <= 10; e++)`

to

`for (int e = 0; e <= 9; e++)`

You can't insert at index 1 if the list is empty.

Comment: Side note: it is very unusual to have `<=` in `for` loops. On other hand force readers to pay attention :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, just wanted to modify the little as possible of his code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in loop, you start it from 1 and try to do insertion in index 1 at the first time. But list can't insert in index if it more than it's size. So, start loop from 0 index.

```
for (int e = 0; e < 10; e++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("what are your favorite game" + e);
    f = Console.ReadLine();
    games.Insert(e, f);
}
```

Reference. List `Insert` method:

```
public void Insert(int index, T item)
{
  if ((uint) index > (uint) this._size)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.index, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_ListInsert);
  if (this._size == this._items.Length)
    this.EnsureCapacity(this._size + 1);
  if (index < this._size)
    Array.Copy((Array) this._items, index, (Array) this._items, index + 1, this._size - index);
  this._items[index] = item;
  this._size = this._size + 1;
  this._version = this._version + 1;
}
```

You can see, it checks index at first.

Comment: Do you *really* need `ToString()`?

Answer (score 0):

games.Insert(e,f) will not work because you can't insert an item on a non-existing index.

games.Add(f) will work because the Add() method adds an item to a list sequentially. It generates the next index of the list and assigns the new value to it.

Insert(index, value) can only work if you have already added the value at the index using Add() method. Please refer to [List.Insert Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx)